# Grunt minified JS and CSS files with version in browser cache

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js, browser-cache, grunt-contrib-concat

We are using grunt for first time in our project and i have spend considerable time on google and stackoverflow but couldn't find the solution to it,currently i have minified JS and CSS file but on browser i want to add version to minified JS and CSS file which are `production.js` and `production.css` so is there any way using grunt or in node to add version to file in browser cache whenever assets(js and css) files are modified

**Concat.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.config.set('concat', {


    dist: {
        src: ['assets/styles/style.css','assets/styles/bootstrap.css', 'assets/styles/font-awesome.css','assets/styles/jquery-ui.css'],
        dest: 'assets/concat/production.css'
    },

  js: {
        src: ['assets/js/src/jquery-2.1.3.js',


    assets/js/src/jquery-ui.js',


 'assets/js/src/bootstrap.js',

 'assets/js/src/bootstrap-switch.js',

 'assets/js/src/moment.js',

 'assets/js/src/angular.js',


 'assets/js/jquery.gritter.min.js',

 'assets/js/dependencies/elements.js',

 'assets/js/dependencies/layout.js',

  'assets/js/dependencies/init.js',

 'assets/js/dependencies/js_importer.js',

 'assets/js/dependencies/sib_common.js',

  'assets/js/angular-sanitize.min.js',

  'assets/js/angular/home.js'

],
        dest: 'assets/concat/production.js'
    }
});
```

**Index.ejs**

```
<html lang="en">

<script src="/concat/production.js"></script>
<head>
<link href="/concat/production.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Implementing using **filerev** but version not created

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
```

grunt.config.set('filerev', {

```
filerev: {
  options: {
    algorithm: 'md5',
    length: 8
  },
  files: {

    src: ['assets/concat/production.js', 'assets/concat/production.css']

  }
}
```

});

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-filerev');
```

};

**default.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {




grunt.registerTask('default', 


['compileAssets', 'linkAssets','filerev' , 'watch']);



};
```

Comment: Have you had a look on `file-rev`? https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev

Comment: @Charminbear    yes but not able to work it out

Comment: How did you implement it? File-rev is the way to go here for Cache-Busting.

Comment: @Charminbear EDITED question and  implemented using `filerev` but still not working as no version is created please help me out!

Comment: @davidwarne, did you ever work this out? I'm trying to bust cache in sails projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'grunt-cache-breaker'

[npmjs/grunt-cache-breaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cache-breaker)